# how to inspect golang code and ignore vendor library

Tags: go

I want to use gometalinter on my local project, the problem is when I run it like `gometalinter ./...` its inspect also the `vendor` folder which I want to ignore, I try to find somthing and find this
`gometalinter ./... -excludepkg ./vendor...` which doesnt help, also the **vendor** lib is inspected, any idea how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per `gometalinter --help`:

```
  --vendor                 Enable vendoring support (skips 'vendor' directories and sets GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1).
```

Comment: when I run `gometalinter --vendor` on my root project I got nothing ...